# Extending Warranty - AppleCare Protection Plan

Tags: iphone, warranty

I have a problem with the phone screen.

I set up a repair with apple today and I noticed that the warranty expires in just 3 days.
Would the repair be handled as a warranty or am I expected to purchase the [AppleCare Protection Plan](http://store.apple.com/ie/product/APP_IPHONE-101078?mco=MTYzNjAwNzM) to ensure that the repair is treated as within warranty

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as long as your case is documented by the Genius before your warranty expires it will be covered under warranty (as long as there are no signs of physical or liquid damage.)  in some cases a Genius will cover items under warranty even a few days after it has expired.

Comment: thanks Ryan, it is not a physical damage so hopefully it should be fine. What do you mean when you say that " in some cases a Genius will cover items under warranty even a few days after it has expired" ? thanks

Comment: If a product is out of warranty by a few days the Genius has the ability to still replace it under warranty for customer appeasement.

Answer (score 1):

What @Ryan said is correct, however, if you intend to purchase the AppleCare, you are supposed to do it *before* your one-year warranty expires. If you’re in Europe, you have two years with/without AppleCare, by law; *unless* you made the purchase through a company (i.e. the invoice is a company and not an individual).

Comment: thanks Martin, I am actually in Europe (Ireland). Would that mean that the warranty is 2 years? I believe that when I checked on the apple website it was just one year. Would the second year be provided by the shop I bought it from or by apple directly?

Comment: @Krisf I’m not 100% sure about Ireland, but I know that here (Spain) even when Apple states 1 year, you’re eligible to a 2nd year. Yes, you can take it to the shop and ask them. I know because it happened to me twice that I had a motherboard failure almost close to two years and they repaired it. I consulted them about that and they said: “it’s by law, Apple must do that here”. And the last time it happened (yes i had that bad luck), they couldn’t do it because I had used the company’s information to buy it, and this is only to individuals. :S Just ask them, may be different in ireland. Gluck.

Comment: thanks again Martin, that is probably some EU law, still it seems strange that on the official apples site it states 1 year, but is good to know in case something goes wrong in the future. Hopefully I will not need to use it though.